# Texture not loading in render view Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

For some reason my Blender doesn't want to load the texture in render mode.
Texture is loaded by Blender with no issues, I can see it in texture mode, in preview of material. Just not on the model itself. Instead I get pink error of no texture.
[image: Render view]

[image: material preview]

[image: Node setup]

[image: Texture mode, texture is that dark, had to zoom in]
[image: Material mode to brighten the texture preview]

Comment: unwrap the mesh

Comment: What's the point of unwarping the mesh if the UV is correct? It just doesn't load the texture in RENDER VIEW.

Comment: have you change from solid mode to texture mode

Comment: To make the texture noticable (because otherwise it's very dark) I print screened here the Material Viewmode. And as you see it loads texture there fine. Render Viewmode? Nope.

Comment: I think u have texture painted. If yes then did u save the image. If not then plz save the image (f3) save blend file restart the blend file

Comment: This is a texture loaded from a file.

Comment: i have given the solution above to save the file with F3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this one was saving file (that was dds) as png and loading the texture from png file.